# What's the mathematical formulation for frames for reference?

Tags: reference-request, physics, coordinate-systems

In [this lecture](http://videolectures.net/mit2003f07_sarma_lec01/) I've come across an interesting formulation of kinematics and reference frames. When I studied kinematics, the idea of what is meant by a 'frame of reference' was never quite fully esplained, and I've never had the notion of taking time derivatives with respect to various frames of ref. impressed upon me. The course uses [this textbook](http://web.mit.edu/jhwill/www/textbook.html) which I unfortunately wasn't able to get as of yet. The course is intended for engineers, so precise mathematical foundations are unnecessary for them, but I find this idea of derivatives being taken w.r.t. different frames very intriguing. Surely it must be a part of a more rigorous formulation of kinematics, but so far I had no luck finding anything of the sort. I would appreciate any reference!

Comment: Ultimately, the mathematical notion you're looking for is that of a moving frame (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_frame), but it is usually discussed in far greater differential-geometric generality than what you're probably looking for. However, if you're comfortable with Lie groups, then for your purposes, a frame of reference is a one-parameter family $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to SE(3)$, where $SE(3)$ denotes the Euclidean group; then for any $r \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\phi_t(r) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is the vector $v$ in the frame of reference $\phi_t$ defined by $\phi$ at time $t$.

Comment: As an example, if $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\phi_t : x \mapsto x + tv$ corresponds to an inertial frame of reference moving at constant velocity $v$ and with origin $tv$ at time $t$; if $R_{\theta,\hat{n}}$ denotes rotation by the angle $\theta$ about the axis $\hat{n}$, then for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\phi_t : x \mapsto R_{\alpha t,\hat{n}}(x)$ corresponds to a rotating frame of reference rotating with angular velocity $\alpha \hat{n}$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar at all with differential geometry or group theory (yet!), so I guess this is out of my reach for now. But it's good to have a motivating example to begin the study of a new topic, so I'll keep this in mind.